# Asymptotic expansion of $y = -A \tan x - \epsilon B \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Let $A,B$ be constants, $\epsilon$ a small parameter, and $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ s.t. $\epsilon\ll|\cos(x)|$. I would like to solve the equation
$$
y = -A \tan x - \epsilon B \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\qquad\qquad (1)
$$
for $x$ using asymptotic expansions. The unperturbed problem yields
$$
x = \tan^{-1}(-\frac{y}{A}).
$$
The Maclaurin series expansions are
$$
\frac{1}{\cos x} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{5}{24}x^4 + ...
$$
and
$$
\tan x = x + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{2}{15}x^5 + ...
$$
Equation (1) then becomes
$$
y = -B\epsilon - Ax - \frac{1}{2}B\epsilon x^2 - \frac{1}{3}Ax^3 - \frac{5}{24}B\epsilon x^4 - \frac{2}{15}Ax^5 - ...
$$
Using the power series ansatz
$$
x_\epsilon = x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2 x_3 + ...
$$
equation (1) after some simplifications becomes
$$
y = G_0 + \epsilon G_1 + \epsilon^2 G_2 + ...
$$
with
$$
G_0 = -Ax_0 - \frac{1}{3}Ax_0^3 - \frac{2}{15}Ax_0^5 - ...\\
G_1 = -Ax_1 - Ax_0^2x_1 - \frac{2}{3}Ax_0^4x_1 - B - \frac{1}{2}Bx_0^2 - \frac{5}{24}Bx_0^4 - ...\\
G_2 = -Ax_2 - Ax_2x_0^2 - \frac{2}{3}Ax_0^4x_2 - Ax_0x_1^2 - \frac{4}{3}Ax_0^3x_1^2 - Bx_0x_1 - \frac{5}{6}Bx_0^3x_1 - ...
$$
This yields the $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^0)$-Problem
$$
y = -Ax_0 - \frac{1}{3}Ax_0^3 - \frac{2}{15}Ax_0^5 - ...
$$
hence
$$
-\frac{y}{A} = x_0 + \frac{1}{3}x_0^3 + \frac{2}{15}x_0^5 + ... = \tan(x_0)
$$
which as expected gives
$$
x_0 = \tan^{-1}(-\frac{y}{A}).
$$
The $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^1)$-Problem yields
$$
0 = Ax_1 + Ax_0^2x_1 + \frac{2}{3}Ax_0^4x_1 + B + \frac{1}{2}Bx_0^2 + \frac{5}{24}Bx_0^4
$$
i.e.,
$$
x_1 = -\frac{B + \frac{1}{2}Bx_0^2 + \frac{5}{24}Bx_0^4}{A + Ax_0^2 + \frac{2}{3}x_0^4}.
$$
I will save the effort for copying the $x_2$ part of the expansion, because I am not too confident that I am on the right track.

EDIT: I have made a mistake when computing the $x_0$-Solution. Corrected that. Now, I am asking more about confirmation, I guess.

Comment: If $\cos x$ is close to $0$ then the perturbation is too big.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Where do you see that and what does it mean?

Comment: If $\cos x=\epsilon^{100}$, then the "error" $\epsilon/\cos x=1/\epsilon^{99}$ is very large.

Comment: Sorry, I misread something. Yes that is true, and indeed $x$ could be arbitrarily close to $\pm\pi/2$. How about making the interval smaller then (still centered at x=0)? Since I am using the Maclaurin series, I would expect the approximation to get worse when away from $x=0$ anyway.

Comment: It is your question. Change it as you see fit.

Comment: I have added a restriction. However, I am still not too sure that this really is a problem, since whenever $\cos(x)$ is close to 0, $\tan(x)$ is super large..

Comment: Can you combine the Maclaurin series for tan x with the one for sec x ?

Comment: Have made the edit with the intermediate step, if that is what you meant.

Comment: Dang, there was a mistake with the $x_0$ computation...I have corrected that

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\neq \pm\frac \pi2$, multiply by $\cos(x)$ and you need to solve for $x$ the equation
$$A \sin (x)+y \cos (x)+B \epsilon =0 \tag 1$$

Expanded around $x=-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{A}\right)$, we have
$$A \sin (x)+y \cos (x)=A \sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{A^2}}\,\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {\left(x+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{A}\right)\right)^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)! }$$

Let
$$\alpha =A \sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{A^2}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{A}\right)$$ Using series reversion
$$x=-\beta+t+\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{3 t^5}{40}+\frac{5 t^7}{112}+O\left(t^{9}\right)\quad \text{where} \quad t=\frac{B \epsilon }{\alpha }$$

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Why are there two solutions, though? The unperturbed problem is monotonely decreasing, so I would expect only one solution...

Comment: @emma. Answer totally revised

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense to expand around the unperturbed solution, now that I see it! Can you say a bit more about the series reversion? I am kind of wondering why I have never seen that with regards to asymptotic expansions...